# tenant-specific endpoint

Tags: hyperforce

We are soon to be moved to Hyperforce and I need to ensure I carry out any necessary changes. I have gone to Data Management/FTP Accounts and at the top I can see the host address. It starts with mc and is 28 characters, then: '.ftp.marketingcloudops.com'
Is this the tenant-specific endpoint and is this ok for Hyperforce? Also, Under File Locations, we have ExactTarget Enhanced FTP, not sure if this is relevant to the question.
thanks for any advice